# Excluding a string name when it partially matches with any element of a list

Tags: python, regex, string, list

I am using Python3 to read AWS bucket names and specifically exit from the loop if the bucket name matches partially with any of the names defined in the `bucket_exclusion_list` array.

I created a bucket validation function as follows:

```
def valid_bucket(bucket_name):
    bucket_exclusion_list = ['do-not-delete', 'aws-config', 'elasticbeanstalk']
    for exclusion_items in bucket_exclusion_list:
        if bool(re.match(exclusion_items, bucket_name)) == True:
            return False
        else:
            continue
    return True
```

In my main function, I am calling the `valid_bucket` function and based on the boolean value, continuing further in the code.

```
if valid_bucket(bucket_name):
   bucket_info["bucketName"] = bucket_name
   bucket_info["bucketSize"] = ''
   ...
```

The code doesn't seem to be working as expected. I have to move on to the next bucket name if the current bucket name matches with the items in the exclusion list. Can someone help me understand the problem with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.match` will only match the beginning of the string. You can use `in` instead of a regex:

```
if exclusion_items in bucket_name:
    return False
else:
    continue
```

That being said, this function can be rewritten as:

```
def valid_bucket(bucket_name):
    bucket_exclusion_list = ['do-not-delete', 'aws-config', 'elasticbeanstalk']
    return all(item not in bucket_name for item in bucket_exclusion_list)
```

Comment: Thanks @Selcuk. Didnt know about the all() function. Thanks for the input.

Comment: All good. Also see the `any()` built-in function if you are curious.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your function as below:

```
import re
def valid_bucket(bucket_name):
    bucket_exclusion_list = ['do-not-delete', 'aws-config', 'elasticbeanstalk']
    regex = "|".join(bucket_exclusion_list)
    if re.search(rf'{regex}', bucket_name):
        return True
    return False

if (valid_bucket(bucket_name)):
    print ("VALID")
else:
    print ("INVALID")
```

Output with bucket name = `my-bucket`

```
INVALID
```

Output with bucket name = `do-not-delete my-bucket`

```
VALID
```